# Rails 3.2/Heroku issue - Precompiling .mp4 videos in public/videos

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html5-video, precompile

New to rails here:
I have a rails app and I'd like to place videos on a page or two using html5 video tags. I am currently using Rails 3.2 and Heroku's cedar stack to deploy my app. I am running into an issue when deploying my app to Heroku.

I have placed my .mp4 videos in **public/videos**, and when running rails' local server, everything works just fine.

However, when I deploy to heroku, the pages containing these videos do not load, i.e. "We're sorry but something went wrong". 
Checking the logs

```
heroku logs
```

shows this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (car_circle.mp4 isn't precompiled)
```

this isn't too surprising, since it seems the public folder isn't included in the rails 3.2 asset pipeline, and so everything in there doesn't get precompiled.

If my reasoning here is correct, I'd like to know how I can get public/videos included in my asset pipeline, so that these videos can be precompiled. Alternately, if I shouldn't have these videos in /public, some guidance on how to correctly move them into the asset pipeline would be great as well.

Hope I've provided enough information for you all to give me a hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/videos"
```

to **config/application.rb** allowed the folder /public/videos to be added to the asset pipeline. This allowed the pages with videos on them to load, however, the page still doesn't load the videos correctly.

This appended the path to the asset pipeline. The paths in the asset pipeline can be viewed by opening the rails console, and typing:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

You will likely encounter a list like this:

```
 => ["/Users/someuser/Documents/Rails/some_app/app/assets/images", 
"/Users/someuser/Documents/some_app/app/assets/javascripts",...,
/Users/someuser/Documents/some_app/public/videos"]
```